# How to assign a specific value to a dataframe from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1:
date         open high low close
2022-03-01   11   33   5   22
2022-03-02   12   34   6   23
2022-03-03   13   35   7   24
2022-03-04   14   36   8   25
2022-03-05   15   37   9   26
2022-03-06   16   38   10  27
......

df2:
date         close 
2022-03-01   22    
2022-03-04   25
2022-03-06   27
......
```

I have two df like above. And I want to add a 'high' column to df2. The 'high' value for each row should be the highest 'high' value during the same duration in the df1. Like in the second row of df2, it's date is between 2022-03-01 and 2022-03-04. And in the same duration in df1, the highest 'high' value is 36, so the second row of df2['high'] should be 36, so on and so forth. What should I do?

I've tried many ways, include below:

```
joined_df = df1.join(df2, how='inner')
high_values = joined_df.groupby(joined_df.index)['high'].max()
df2['high'] = df1.index.map(high_values)
```

But all method didn't work, so please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) as your indexes are sorted:

```
g = np.searchsorted(df2.index, df1.index, side='left')
df2['high'] = df1.groupby(g)['high'].max().values
print(df2)

# Output
            close  high
date                   
2022-03-01     22    33
2022-03-04     25    36
2022-03-06     27    38
```

Note, you can also use `side='right'` to have a different result:

```
g = np.searchsorted(df2.index, df1.index, side='right')
df2['high'] = df1.groupby(g)['high'].max().values
print(df2)

# Output
            close  high
date                   
2022-03-01     22    35
2022-03-04     25    37
2022-03-06     27    38
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but seems like we should add: "[:-1]" after "df1.groupby(g)['high'].max().values", so that the redundant datas won't calculated.

Comment: Do you mean no value is needed for the last row (2022-03-06)?

Comment: yes, since the -1 row using datas from -2 to -1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates are sorted in the two dataframes, you can create a custom grouper with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) and get the max value per group with [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html). Then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
group = df1['date'].where(df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])).bfill()

out = df2.merge(df1.groupby(group)['high'].max(), left_on='date', right_index=True)

# or
# out = df2.merge(df1.groupby(group)['high'].max().reset_index())
```

Output:

```
         date  close  high
0  2022-03-01     22    33
1  2022-03-04     25    36
2  2022-03-06     27    38
```

Intermediates:

```
group

0    2022-03-01
1    2022-03-04
2    2022-03-04
3    2022-03-04
4    2022-03-06
5    2022-03-06
Name: date, dtype: object

df1.groupby(group)['high'].max()

date
2022-03-01    33
2022-03-04    36
2022-03-06    38
Name: high, dtype: int64
```

##### date as index

Either `reset_index` and use the above, or use:

```
group = df1.index.where(df1.index.isin(df2.index)).to_series().bfill().tolist()

out = df2.merge(df1.groupby(group)['high'].max(), left_on='date', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
            close  high
date                   
2022-03-01     22    33
2022-03-04     25    36
2022-03-06     27    38
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but the 'date' is the index for the df1 and df2, so I can't directly use this way that you just show, could you also tell me how to solve this problem at this situation?

Comment: @rusty_nakata I updated my answer, see the bottom part

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with aggregate `max` with mapping to new column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2['high'] = (df2['date'].map(pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                                             df2.rename(columns={'date':'d1'}), 
                                             left_on='date', 
                                             right_on='d1',
                                             direction='forward')
                                 .groupby('d1')['high'].max()))
print (df2)
        date  close  high
0 2022-03-01     22    33
1 2022-03-04     25    36
2 2022-03-06     27    38
```

How it working:

```
print (pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                     df2.rename(columns={'date':'d1'}), 
                     left_on='date', 
                     right_on='d1',
                     direction='forward'))

        date  open  high  low  close_x         d1  close_y
0 2022-03-01    11    33    5       22 2022-03-01       22
1 2022-03-02    12    34    6       23 2022-03-04       25
2 2022-03-03    13    35    7       24 2022-03-04       25
3 2022-03-04    14    36    8       25 2022-03-04       25
4 2022-03-05    15    37    9       26 2022-03-06       27
5 2022-03-06    16    38   10       27 2022-03-06       27
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but the 'date' is the index for the df1 and df2, so I can't directly use this way that you just show, could you also tell me how to solve this problem at this situation?